# How to iterate foreach loop for a particular array size

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I'm having two different for-each loop as below

```
 <div id="filterarea" data-bind="foreach: { data: filters, as: 'filtercategory' }  ">
     <ul data-bind="foreach: { data: Refiners, as: 'refiner' } ">
          //display data
      </ul>
 </div>
```

should iterate for less than 2 and render inner tags

Comment: What exactly should be less than two?

Comment: @James Thorpe i'm rendering some tags based on json

Comment: But what part of it is the `<2` check supposed to be against?

Comment: observableArray `length` are you referring to ? its not clear

Comment: @James Thorpe  inside the 'data: filters' and 'data: Refiners' for-each

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking at the moment - you must have something within the data you're looping over that you want to compare against `2`.  What specifically is it?  Seeing your viewmodel might help.

Comment: @James Thorpe i  wanna iterate `for-each`  loop for  `< 2 ` is there any way to do it

Comment: @super cool no its not bservableArray `length`

Comment: may be you should looking for this http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/25267/ . let us know

Comment: @super cool no i wanna iterate `for-each`  loop up till 2 elements of  `data: filters` instaed of whole length

Comment: then simple use `data: filters().slice(1,3)` in your view simple check here http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/25268/

Comment: @super cool thanks dude...got it what i expected :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well you just need to `slice` it up if you want to loop through particular elements

**view:**

```
<div id="filterarea" data-bind="foreach: { data: filters().slice(1,3), as: 'filtercategory' }  ">
    <span data-bind="text:$index"></span>
     <ul data-bind="foreach: { data: $root.Refiners().slice(1,3), as: 'refiner' } ">
          <span data-bind="text:$index"></span>
          //display data
      </ul>
 </div>
```

> The slice function is the observableArray equivalent of the native
>   JavaScript slice function (i.e., it returns the entries of your array
>   from a given start index up to a given end index). Calling
>   myObservableArray.slice(...) is equivalent to calling the same method
>   on the underlying array (i.e., myObservableArray().slice(...))

working sample up **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/25268/)**